# Function producing while loop runtime error?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, runtime

I am completing exercises for my intro to computer programming class. When trying to run this function, it comes up with a runtime error and can't complete the task, can someone please enlighten me!

```
def num_rushes(slope_height, rush_height_gain, back_sliding):

    current_height = 0 
    rushes = 0
    while current_height < slope_height:  
        rush_height_gain = 0.95**rushes * rush_height_gain
        back_sliding = 0.95**rushes * back_sliding
        if (current_height + rush_height_gain) >= slope_height:
            return rushes + 1
        else:
            current_height += (rush_height_gain - back_sliding)
            rushes += 1
ans = num_rushes(100, 15, 7)
print(ans)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: The call shown here never terminates; `current_height` only gets to about 44.5 before `rush_height_gain` reaches 0, far short of the value of `slope_height` given.

Comment: **Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.**